# ImageView in expandable list

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to create an expendable list with text as well as an ImageView. This is how I'm currently doing this: There's one parent xaml and two children xaml (a ChildText.xaml and a ChildImage.xaml). I want one of the parent items to contain an image. I used following code in my adapter:

```
public override View GetChildView (int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    var item = _dictGroup [_lstGroupID [groupPosition]] [childPosition];
    if(item.Contains("ichart")) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ListControl_ImageChild, null);

            var imageView = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image);
            var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl (item);
            imageView.SetImageBitmap (imageBitmap); //X

    } else {
        string[] data = item.Split ('_');

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ListControl_Child, null);

        var titleBox = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.titleSmall);
        var textBox = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtSmall);
        titleBox.SetText (data[0], TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        textBox.SetText (data[1], TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

So if the string contains ichart, it should create an ImageView. This works, but when I try to click open another tab (containing text), I get a nullpointer exception on the line with the X saying imageView is null. Why is it entering that if?

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all we have to make an array of images & parent names we want to put in expandable list view. Then call these arrays by using array adapter class.
you have to put the first variable manually in .xml file after that array adapter set all images & textview as per array you made.

Comment: Mayank, can you please provide some example code along with your answer? It might be a little difficult to understand just providing an explanation.

Comment: This would be very helpful.